# Post installation error "DeployedItems.xml" with Sitecore TDS

Tags: sitecore, tds

I created a TDS package of a project and wanted to install it on a fresh Sitecore instance. At the end of the installation I get this message:

[image]

What does this error mean? What is this "DeployedItems.xml"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my recollection, the DeployedItems.xml is a file created by TDS in the _DEV folder to track which items were installed. Are you running Sitecore 8 Update 3? Did you include files in the package?

If so, the following link might provide you details on the issue:
http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2015/may/sitecore-update-installation-wizard-error-in-sitecore-8-update-3.aspx

From that post:

> To resolve the issue, you need to add a few lines to the Sitecore web.config.
>
> 1. Locate the `<configSections>` element at the top of the web.config
> 2. Add the section "`<section name="sitecorediff" type="Sitecore.Update.Configuration.ConfigReader, Sitecore.Update"/>`"
> 3. Right after the close of the  element add "`<sitecorediff/>`" element

TDS 5.1.0.9 contains the fix for this issue, so if you are on a version below that, you may want to update your TDS version.

Comment: I'm running TDS 5.1.0.11, but I'll try that anyway.